# Jquery code not working in IE 9 but works in FF and Chrome

Tags: jquery

I have this JQuery to show/hide rows that is not working in IE9 and it is extremely time sensitive and I have absolutely no idea how to fix it. I tried adding a meta tag for IE8 which made it work but completely messed up the formatting. I am unsure of its native functionality in IE8. It does function in Firefox and Chrome.

```
function showNext(opt)  {       
      takeAway();     

      var optMap={
             "Picked Up":"#pickedup",
             "Bus to alternate":"#altad2,#altad1",
             "Walk to alternate":"#altad2,#altad1",
              };
           $(optMap[opt]).css("display","") ;       

}
```

The function is called here

```
<tr class="~[evenoddrow]"> 
        <td class="bold">In the event of early dismissal I would like my child to:</td><td id="Emergclose_Action">~([01]Emergclose_Action)</td><td class="gwCen"></td>
        <td><select name="eReg|Emergclose_Action" id="eReg|Emergclose_Action" onChange="showNext(value);">
                <option></option><option value="Walk home as normal">Walk home as normal</option><option value="Ride the bus as normal">Ride the bus as normal</option>
<option value="Picked Up">Be picked up immediately after dismissal</option><option value="Bus to alternate">Ride the bus to an alternate address</option><option value="Walk to alternate">Walk to an alternate address</option>
            </select>           
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The displayed rows are below

```
<tr class="~[evenoddrow]" id="pickedup" style="display:none;"> 
<td class="bold">Name of the person that will be picking up your child:</td><td id="Emergclose_Who_Pickup">~([01]Emergclose_Who_Pickup)</td><td class="gwCen"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="eReg|Emergclose_Who_Pickup" id="eReg|Emergclose_Who_Pickup" value="" size="30" /><span class="gwExample">last,&nbsp; first</span></td>
    </tr>
<tr class="~[evenoddrow]"  id="altad1" style="display:none;"> 
        <td class="bold"><span style="padding: 0 25px">I would like my child to go to the home of:</td></span><td id="Emergclose_Alt_Name">~([01]Emergclose_Alt_Name)</td><td class="gwCen"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="eReg|Emergclose_Alt_Name" id="eReg|Emergclose_Alt_Name" value="" size="30" /><span class="gwExample">last,&nbsp; first</span></td>
    </tr>   
<tr class="~[evenoddrow]" id="altad2" style="display:none;"> 
        <td class="bold"><span style="padding: 0 25px">Address of Alternate Location:</td></span><td id="Emergclose_Alt_Address">~([01]Emergclose_Alt_Address)</td><td class="gwCen"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="eReg|Emergclose_Alt_Address" id="eReg|Emergclose_Alt_Address" value="" size="30" /><span class="gwExample">Street Address, City, State, Zip</span></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Remove the comma on the final line of optMap

Comment: Did that but no effect

Comment: It's still necessary for some versions of IE - they don't like the trailing comma, whereas other browsers just ignore it.  Worth keeping in mind :)

Comment: What happens if you removed the `style="display:none;"`, and instead add a class with CSS `.myClassHider{display:none;}`, then add/remove that class as needed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a 'toggle' going on there, so have you tried setting the display value?

Comment: Beaten to it by seconds :)

Comment: I probably should add this works in Firefox, safari and chrome.. I will edit the post to include additional details

Answer (score 0):

I used this markup: NOTE Removed the style from the markup and the code from the markup:

```
<table>
    <tr class="~[evenoddrow]">
        <td class="bold">In the event of early dismissal I would like my child to:</td>
        <td id="Emergclose_Action">~([01]Emergclose_Action)</td>
        <td class="gwCen"></td>
        <td>
            <select name="eReg|Emergclose_Action" id="eReg|Emergclose_Action" class="myselecitem">
                <option></option>
                <option value="Walk home as normal">Walk home as normal</option>
                <option value="Ride the bus as normal">Ride the bus as normal</option>
                <option value="Picked Up">Be picked up immediately after dismissal</option>
                <option value="Bus to alternate">Ride the bus to an alternate address</option>
                <option value="Walk to alternate">Walk to an alternate address</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="~[evenoddrow] hiddenstuff choice" id="pickedup">
        <td class="bold">Name of the person that will be picking up your child:</td>
        <td id="Emergclose_Who_Pickup">~([01]Emergclose_Who_Pickup)</td>
        <td class="gwCen"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="eReg|Emergclose_Who_Pickup" id="eReg|Emergclose_Who_Pickup" value="" size="30" /><span class="gwExample">last,&nbsp; first</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="~[evenoddrow] hiddenstuff choice" id="altad1">
        <td class="bold"><span style="padding: 0 25px">I would like my child to go to the home of:</td></span>

            <td id="Emergclose_Alt_Name">~([01]Emergclose_Alt_Name)</td>
            <td class="gwCen"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="eReg|Emergclose_Alt_Name" id="eReg|Emergclose_Alt_Name" value="" size="30" /><span class="gwExample">last,&nbsp; first</span>

            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="~[evenoddrow] hiddenstuff choice" id="altad2">
        <td class="bold"><span style="padding: 0 25px">Address of Alternate Location:</td></span>

            <td id="Emergclose_Alt_Address">~([01]Emergclose_Alt_Address)</td>
            <td class="gwCen"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="eReg|Emergclose_Alt_Address" id="eReg|Emergclose_Alt_Address" value="" size="30" /><span class="gwExample">Street Address, City, State, Zip</span>

            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This CSS:

```
.clicked {
    background-color:lime;
}
.hiddenstuff {
    display:none;
}
```

This code:

```
function showNext(opt) {
    //    takeAway();
    var optMap = {
        "Picked Up": "#pickedup",
            "Bus to alternate": "#altad2,#altad1",
            "Walk to alternate": "#altad2,#altad1"
    };
    $('#Emergclose_Action').text(optMap[opt]);
    $('.choice').removeClass('clicked').addClass('hiddenstuff');
    $(optMap[opt]).addClass('clicked').removeClass('hiddenstuff');
}
$('.myselecitem').change(function () {
    showNext($(this).val());
});
```

EDIT: Example in use: http://jsbin.com/adexol/2/

Comment: This works wonderfully with one exception.. When you choose an item from the dropdown the value that would normally be the "value listed in database" displays as #altad1 #pickedup etc etc depending on what is chosen in the dropdown.. this value should display the value that is in the database currently before the page is submitted.. I will upload a screenshot so you can see what I am talking about

Comment: http://imgur.com/qpKK16z is the screenshot. Normally where it has #altad1, #altad2 it would say whatever the person had selected last year.. If i remove the class="myselecitem" it shows the correct value but the function no longer works

Comment: The value that gets passed to the database needs to be the Picked Up, Bus to alternate, walk to alternate etc etc

Comment: this line: `$('#Emergclose_Action').text(optMap[opt]);` was put in simply to show the action and is pretty basic, and could be removed. - same with the "clicked" class I added - to show action/highlight as it was doing things. Do you not see/know any of this? Its alright if you don't know but those are pretty basic things really.

Comment: Yeah removing that worked and everything works awesome in IE.. But now it no longer works in FF (the rows are not hiding/showing, they are all just displayed) I really appreciate your assistance and, I am sorry for my ignorance. I know very little about this stuff and I was thrown into it at the last minute and told it needs to be done by Monday.

Comment: Try it without the spaces in the option values and the optMap names. Example: `"Bus to alternate"` change to `"BusAlt"` in both places; likewise with other values.

Comment: No Effect when changing those values :(

Comment: Yeah the stuff in jsbin works on both browsers.. I am not sure what is going on